# How to sync 2 s3 buckets, every day, with 2 different AWS accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have AWS account ACCOUNT-A and a bucket under it BUCKET-DESTINATION.
I have another AWS account ACCOUNT-B, with no access to it, but have been provided with a IAM user IAM-B and a bucket BUCKET-SOURCE that IAM-B has access to (Read/Write).

I want to use IAM-B to sync BUCKET-SOURCE to BUCKET-DESTINATION, every night. If possible all within AWS, I don't want to cron aws sync.

How would I go about doing this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to have a single set of credentials that has:

- Read access to the source bucket, and
- Write access to the destination bucket

Since you have been provided with with IAM User B that has access to the source bucket, and presuming that the destination bucket is under your control, the easiest method would be to **create a bucket policy on the destination bucket** that grants write access (`PutObject`) to that IAM User B.

This way, you can use a single set of credentials that has permission to **read** from the source bucket and **write** to the destination bucket.

**Important:** When writing to a bucket with a set of credentials that does not belong to the same account as the destination bucket, it is important to specify `--acl bucket-owner-full-control`. This sets the 'owner' of the object to the destination account.

It is not possible to schedule an AWS CLI sync operation within S3, so your choices are:

- Use a cron job on a computer somewhere on the Internet, or
- Schedule an AWS Lambda function that will copy the objects, using hard-coded credentials to operate as IAM User B rather than as the IAM Role assigned to the function, or
- Have Account-B configure [S3 Replication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/replication.html) so that S3 immediately replicates objects between the buckets (without having to call a Copy command)

The last option is by far the easiest! (It would require a bucket policy on the destination bucket that permits the replication process to write objects to the bucket.)

Comment: Thank you for you help!

Comment: I used a lambda function to copy objects to a /tmp folder and from that /tmp folder copied over to my own s3 bucket.

Answer (score 2):

You could set up S3 bucket replication across the two different accounts. The replication works asynchronously (usually within 15min, but sometimes up to a couple of hours as described in [How long does object replication take on Amazon S3?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-object-replication-time/)). No additional services are needed to trigger the replication.

You will need to give account A permissions on bucket B (target bucket) via a bucket policy in order for the replication to work. The detailed configuration description can be found in [Configuring replication when source and destination buckets are owned by different accounts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/replication-walkthrough-2.html).

Comment: Thank you for you help!